# Why parent component does not update input component when setting state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a input component like this:

```
let InputBasic = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'InputBasic',
    path: '',
    componentWillMount: function () {
        this.path = this.props.storePath + '.' + this.props.storeIndex;
    },

    getInitialState: function () {
        return { };
    },

    getError: function () {
        if (!Array.isArray(this.props.formErrorFields)) {
            return false;
        };

        __this = this;
        let hasError = false;
        this.props.formErrorFields.forEach(function (index) {
            if (__this.props.name == index.name) {
                hasError = true;
                return;
            }
        });

        return hasError;
    },

    sendToValidation: function() {
        if (this.props.rules) {
            bom.form.validateInput(
            /* Vars here */
            );
        }
    },

    getClassName: function () {

        if(this.getError()) {

            return 'input-basic has-error';
        }
        else {
            return 'input-basic';
        }
    },

    onBlur: function () {
        this.sendToValidation();
    },

    handleChange: function (event) {
        this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
    },

    render: function () {

        return React.createElement('input',
            {
                type: this.props.type,
                placeholder: this.props.placeholder,
                style: this.props.style,
                onChange: this.handleChange,
                onBlur: this.onBlur,
                className: this.getClassName()
            }
        );
    }
});
```

The idea is to validate input field on blur. If the input doesn't pass the validation, the containing form state is altered. The form setState() function is passed to the input as a prop, then to the validation and so on.

The logic works in setting the form state. The form state is set accordingly. I also have a another component, which is dependant on the form state and that works perfectly. However, the input component is not updated as I was expecting.

In following scenario I have problems:

- Empty, initial input -> Click to trigger onBlur -> validation fails -> input component updates
- Type in to input -> Click to trigger onBlur -> validation success -> input component updates
- Remove text again from input -> Click to trigger onBlur -> validation fail -> input component does not update
- Add text again to input -> Click to trigger onBlur -> validation succes -> input component does update

This is peculiar, since other elements inside form are updated. If I add forceUpdate() to the onBlur function, the component updates as expected. However, this solution feels hacky, especially because I don't understand why I don't get the desired effect otherwise.

Things which came in to my mind while trying to solve this:

- Can this be caused by the fact, that the component is triggering the update process which eventually points to itself? What I try to ask here is that is it a problem that I am passing the setState function down as a prop?
- Are input components treated somehow differently, when it comes to updating?

EDIT:

Could this be caused because of onChange function? It is not in the example, since SO nagged about too long code sample.

MORE EDIT:

Apparently how I assign the value to the state affects if the update on children is launched.

This is the function which I use to update the state of the input parent:

```
bom.form = {

    getErrorField: function (fields, name, text) {
        let newFields = fields;
        if (fields[name]) {
            newFields[name].hasError = true;
            newFields[name].errorText = text;
        }
        return newFields;

    },

    validateInput: function (inputValue, inputName, inputRules, setFormState, formFields) {
        let fields = formFields;
        if (!inputValue && inputRules.required) {
            let text = 'This field is required.';
            fields = this.getErrorField(formFields, inputName, text);
        }
        state = {};
        state.fields = fields;

        return setFormState(state);
    }
};
```

So, calling validateInput() my I set parent component state of the input.

This does not launch the update in the input component. However, if I change state.fields assignment in example to this:

```
state.fields = { password: {}, username: {}}
```

It launches the update as desired. And of course, in this example the state is not what I want, this is just for presentational purposes.

The peculiar thing is that in both of these cases the other, different child component (which I call fieldMessage) updates. It is rendered this way:

```
return React.createElement('p', null, this.getText());
```

The getText() function returns parent component state, which is pointed to right field.

So I have became in to conclusion, that my problem has something to do how I assign the state object to setState() function. Am I correct? Can this happen because I pass the current state to the child function and am I possibly using object reference to original in a wrong place, or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding your `onBlur` handler to your react class. In particular:

```
render: function () {

    return React.createElement('input',
        {
            type: this.props.type,
            placeholder: this.props.placeholder,
            style: this.props.style,
            onChange: this.handleChange,
            onBlur: this.onBlur.bind(this),
            className: this.getClassName()
        }
    );
}
```

This is because, `this.sendToValidation();` ends up being called bound to the event target.

Comment: Not working. Besides, remember that the other related components are updated accordingly, so the state of the parent is actually changed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by assigning the state.fields like this:

```
state.fields = Object.create(fields);
```

I assume that originally the fields were pointing to original state object reference and therefore did not launch the update. However, this is really just my guess and if somebody can clarify the behaviour to me I would be very grateful.